# Mootools - How to get droppables css stats?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, mootools

Hiya guys heres my question:

im using mootools and im using this demo-> [Drag.Move](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Move)!

everything works fine but i want to drop the item and modify the draggable items css position to that of the droppable item, just cant get the droppagble items stats i dont know how :S 
here is where the code goes of when i drop the item:

```
    onDrop: function(element, droppable){
      if (droppable) droppable.setStyle('background', '#C17878');
    }
```

thats how to set them but i want something like this:

```
    onDrop: function(element, droppable){
      if (droppable) {
                    element.left = droppable.left;  
                    element.top = droppable.top;  
                     }
    }
```

any help would be great!

ty in advance!

-Thaiscorpion.

SOLVED:

```
    onDrop: function(element, droppable){
      if (droppable) 
      {
        var snap_left = droppable.getStyle('left');
        var snap_top = droppable.getStyle('top');
        element.setStyle('left', snap_left );
        element.setStyle('top', snap_top );
      }
    }
```

this worked for me in the end! hope it helps someone else!

Comment: Put the 'solved' part as an answer and mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could do it in one line, with getStyles/setStyles instead of getStyle/setStyle.

```
onDrop: function(element, droppable){
  if (droppable) element.setStyles(droppable.getStyles('left', 'top'));
}
```